# CSS - Equal size images

Tags: css

How can I make all the images the same size while having them still be responsive?

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ko9g725/2/

This is all the css:

```
.ui.text.menu {
   background-color: #eee;
   margin-top: 0;
}

.ui.message {
   padding: 50px 50px;
   margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.ui.grid.stackable.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried to get the images to stay responsive?

Comment: Haven't tried much. I'm just looking for a way to size the images without hard-coding the pixels

Comment: bootstrap can do this (i think) if i remember right

Comment: may i know what do you mean by **same size**

Comment: Without setting the columns size that is relative to the image, jQuery library matchHeight is great for this! https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a jsfiddle. [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of many of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+size+images

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2ko9g725/5/). It may help you

CSS

```
img.ui.image{

  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.ui.segment {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have the images stretch on smaller viewports?

Comment: do you prefer bootstrap?

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar sure

Comment: @George currently it shows in actual size without stretch. Do you want to stretch the image? But I feel it's not a good idea for view in the web.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bayleymauger/30fmor6y/2) fiddle. You can put a wrapper div inside your ui segments for your image to sit in, then give that wrapper a height and width then add object-fit: cover to the img element in css with a width and height of 100%.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.segment {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.seg-img {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="segment">
  <div class="seg-img">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464061884326-64f6ebd57f83?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80">
  </div>
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>

<div class="segment">
  <div class="seg-img">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440658172029-9d9e5cdc127c?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1652&q=80">
  </div>
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>

<div class="segment">
  <div class="seg-img">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474015833661-686ed67f9485?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80">
  </div>
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have just updated the fiddle with

> images stretch on smaller viewports  have been fixed

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ko9g725/8/)

i have just changed only in the css

```
    img.ui.image{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```